# Как сделать так, что бы при нажатии кнопки скрывался контейнер?

Tags: c#, winforms

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Я хочу сделать 6 кнопок(button) и 6 контейнеров(tabControl). То есть что бы при нажатии кнопки у меня открывался контейнер, а если я нажимаю на другую кнопку, все остальные контейнеры скрывались из видимости (то есть что бы Visible у них становился =false). Что мне нужно прописать в коде? Кому не сложно, пропишите пожалуйста код, а то уже несколько дней мучаюсь никак не могу написать правильно, все время че то не так

Comment: Пробовали использовать tabControl1.SelectedTab для активации нужного таба?

Comment: .скрин добавил.

Comment: SelectedTab как раз мне не нужен, мне TapPage переключать не надо